# How to transform date/time from input timezone to output timezone in JavaScript / Dayjs?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, dayjs

I have this so far:

```js
import * as chrono from 'chrono-node'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc'
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone'

dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(timezone)

let selectedInput = 'pst'
let selectedOutput = 'est'
let inputDateString = '10pm'

// set timezone reference point to PST
dayjs.tz.setDefault(selectedInput)
const inputDate = chrono.parseDate(inputDateString)
const utc = inputDate?.toISOString().replace(/Z$/, '')
const computedInputDate = utc
  ? dayjs(utc).tz(selectedInput)
  : undefined
const outputDateString = computedInputDate
  ? dayjs(computedInputDate)
      .tz(selectedOutput)
      .format('h:mma on MMM D, YYYY')
  : undefined
dayjs.tz.setDefault() // reset default timezone
console.log('output:', outputDateString)
```

I am using [dayjs timezone](https://day.js.org/docs/en/timezone/converting-to-zone) and [chrono-node](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono) (for the natural language time parsing feature). So in year 2024 on day Jan 31, you type `10pm` (that is, you are saying "10pm Jan 31 2024 PST"), I would expect to see `1:00am on Feb 1, 2024` in the logged output, but instead I am seeing `9:00am on Feb 1, 2024`, what am I doing wrong?

How do you start the time reference point from a particular timezone, and then how do you convert it to the other different timezone? Either using Dayjs (what I'm using), or some other library / native function would be fine.

If I instead remove the UTC conversion stuff, and go with this:

```js
import * as chrono from 'chrono-node'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc'
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone'

dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(timezone)

let selectedInput = 'pst'
let selectedOutput = 'est'
let inputDateString = '10pm'

// set timezone reference point to PST
dayjs.tz.setDefault(selectedInput)
const inputDate = chrono.parseDate(inputDateString)
const computedInputDate = inputDate
  ? dayjs(inputDate).tz(selectedInput)
  : undefined;
const outputDateString = computedInputDate
  ? dayjs(computedInputDate).tz(selectedOutput).format("h:mma on MMM D, YYYY")
  : undefined;
dayjs.tz.setDefault() // reset default timezone
console.log('output:', outputDateString)
```

I get the correct `1:00am on Feb 1, 2024`.

But if I reverse the timezones (EST -> PST), and plug in 10pm, I should see `7:00pm on Jan 31, 2024` (PST), but I see `10:00pm on Jan 31, 2024`, so my calculations aren't quite right in either direction.

```
import * as chrono from 'chrono-node'
import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import utc from 'dayjs/plugin/utc'
import timezone from 'dayjs/plugin/timezone'

dayjs.extend(utc)
dayjs.extend(timezone)

let selectedInput = 'est'
let selectedOutput = 'pst'
let inputDateString = '10pm'

// set timezone reference point to PST
dayjs.tz.setDefault(selectedInput)
const inputDate = chrono.parseDate(inputDateString)
const computedInputDate = inputDate
  ? dayjs(inputDate).tz(selectedInput)
  : undefined;
const outputDateString = computedInputDate
  ? dayjs(computedInputDate).tz(selectedOutput).format("h:mma on MMM D, YYYY")
  : undefined;
dayjs.tz.setDefault() // reset default timezone
console.log('output:', outputDateString)
```

How do I get this working going forward or backward in timezones given an input timezone, output timezone, and input time (natural language)?

#### Update: Tried Luxon

Tried [luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon) but same results pretty much.

```js
const time = '10pm'
const selectedInput = 'EST'
const selectedOutput = 'PST'

const inputDate = chrono.parseDate(time, { timezone: selectedInput })
const outputDate = inputDate
  ? DateTime.fromJSDate(inputDate, { zone: selectedInput }).setZone(
      selectedOutput,
    )
  : undefined
const outputDateString = outputDate
  ? `${outputDate.toFormat('h:mm')}${outputDate
      .toFormat('a')
      .toLowerCase()} on ${outputDate.toFormat('MMM d, yyyy')}`
  : undefined
// says 10pm instead of 7pm
```

Even with IANA location-based timezones, same issue:

```js
const inputDate = chrono.parseDate(time, {
  timezone: 'America/Cancun',
})
const outputDate = inputDate
  ? DateTime.fromJSDate(inputDate, {
      zone: 'America/Cancun',
    }).setZone('America/Los_Angeles')
  : undefined
const outputDateString = outputDate
  ? `${outputDate.toFormat('h:mm')}${outputDate
      .toFormat('a')
      .toLowerCase()} on ${outputDate.toFormat('MMM d, yyyy')}`
  : undefined
// says 10pm, when it should say 7pm.
```

Comment: Did you also try using [IANA timezone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)? So for pst and `America/Los_Angeles` and est `America/New_York`

Comment: See for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/mandy8055/dgjq74et/8/

Comment: @mandy8055 yes I tried, I switched to [luxon](https://github.com/moment/luxon) thinking it might help, but same issue. See my latest update in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using luxon, this seems to work:

```js
import * as chrono from 'chrono-node'
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'

const selectedInput = 'est'
const selectedOutput = 'pst'
const time = '10pm'

const inputDate = chrono.parseDate(time, {
  timezone: selectedInput.toUpperCase(),
  instant: new Date(),
})
const outputDate = inputDate
  ? DateTime.fromJSDate(inputDate).setZone(selectedOutput)
  : undefined
const outputDateString = outputDate
  ? `${outputDate.toFormat('h:mm')}${outputDate
      .toFormat('a')
      .toLowerCase()} on ${outputDate.toFormat('MMM d, yyyy')}`
  : undefined
```

I am still open to seeing a better more robust solution though.